# How unique is the salt produced by this function?

Tags: flutter, security, dart, passwords

I use this function to generate unique salts for each of my users when they sign up (random letters and numbers). How big is the chance that salts will collide?

```
  // length is for the underlying bytes, not the resulting string.
  String generateSalt([int length = 94]) {
    final Random random = Random.secure();
    var values = List<int>.generate(length, (i) => random.nextInt(256));
    return base64Url.encode(values);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to a first approximation they are not going to collide!  in fact I'd suggest making `length` smaller so you don't potentially reveal as much entropy of the RNG

your algorithm currently produces `log2(256**94)` = 8*94 = 752 random bits.  via the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) we know that you'd have to produce `2**(752/2)` = 2<sup>376</sup> values to have a 50% chance of collision.  generating this many values is [impossible](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257323).

lets reduce this down to a more reasonable 2<sup>128</sup> lifetime chance of collision.  this means you'd want 256 random bits generated, and would mean your `length` would be `256/8` = 32.

note that all of the above relies upon `Random.secure` actually being a csPRNG and any attacker not knowing any of its state.  given the above probabilities, this is the much bigger vulnerability of this system